# jqGrid with MVC3 url action not firing

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, razor

I was trying to follow the most recently updated tutorial for jqgrid and MVC3.  I have this script:

```
        myGrid.jqGrid({
            url: '<%= Url.Action("GridData") %>',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'A', index: 'A', key: true, width: 40
                },
                { name: 'B', index: 'B', width: 40
                },
                { name: 'C', index: 'C', width: 400
                }
            ],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'A',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            rownumbers: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            altRows: true,
            //altclass: 'myAltRowClass',
            height: '100%',
            gridview: true,
            jsonReader: { cell: "" },
            caption: 'Grid Title'
        });
```

I have a Controller in the Controllers folder caller HomeController with this inside:

```
public JsonResult GridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            total = 1, // we'll implement later 
            page = page,
            records = 3, // implement later 
            rows = (
                    new[] {
                        new[]{"A", "B", "C"},
                        new[]{"1", "2", "3"},
                        new[]{"X", "Y", "Z"}
            }).ToList()
        });
    }
```

For some reason I can't get GridData to be called.  I set a break point on that function in the controller and it is not being hit.

What could I be missing?  Do I need to setup the routing in the project somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `Url.Action()` call to this:

```
<%= Url.Action("GridData", "Home") %>
```

And just an FYI, this is not Razor syntax.  If you are indeed using Razor, it would look like this:

```
@Url.Action("GridData", "Home")
```

And last point to ask:  where is your JavaScript/jQuery code living?  Is it embedded in your View markup?

Comment: Ah, yes.  It'll take me a little bit to get over the stupidity of that one, even though I am new to Razor (and mvc).

Comment: @DougS. No stupidity at all.  So did that solve your issue then??